# Run macro until the end of the file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

Is there some AddIn or extension for Visual Studio 2008 that will allow me to run Macro until the end of the file? I really hate holding CTRL+SHIFT+P and waiting until end of the file is reached.

Comment: Do you accept solutions that are not free? (External editor)

Comment: I wouldn't go with external editors... because there are bunch of even free alternatives that support this. So Visual Studio 2008 definitely doesn't support Run to the End of the file?! Anyone know what's the situation with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: All right, good to know. And the answer from Cristian here below, is really good.

Comment: I would just add a bit of information on this topic. [Macros in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11). So, perhaps, in the future you will be forced to other solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could record a macro and then open the Macro IDE (Alt + F11) and place the prerecorded macro in a loop like this:

```
Sub TemporaryMacro()
    selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection()
    anchorPoint = selection.AnchorPoint.CreateEditPoint
    selection.EndOfDocument(True)
    endPoint = selection.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint()
    selection.MoveToPoint(anchorPoint)

    Do While True
        isEOF = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint().Line = endPoint.Line
        If (isEOF) Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        ' Prerecorded macro
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = " "
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.LineDown()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.CharLeft()
        ' End of prerecorder macro

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks in any case - I don't like the answer... but it seems nothing better than it can be done.